# Validate a string contains only certain characters in java

Tags: java, validation

Ok, what I am trying to do is take a user input in infix notation and translate it to postfix and then evaluate it. I have that already completed.

What I am struggling with, is for the user input I need to validate that it only contains the following: (), 0-9, +, -, *, /, %

Each character will be separated by a space, so here is a potential valid input:

( 3 + 4 ) * 5 / ( 6 - 7 )

I have created an InvalidCharacterException that I wish to throw if the user string contains anything other than those characters.

Here is what an invalid input would look like:

3 - 5 ^ 5

The ^ would be an invalid character and then I would throw new InvalidCharacterException and ask for a new input.

I will also say I have looked at a ton of regex samples, and to be honest I don't understand what they're doing.

EDIT:

Ok, this is what I ended up implementing because I don't really understand anything else. Any advice on a simpler way?

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= infix.length(); i++){
        if(infix.charAt(i) ==  '(' || infix.charAt(i) == ')' || infix.charAt(i) =='+' 
                || infix.charAt(i) =='-' ||infix.charAt(i) == '*' ||infix.charAt(i) == '/'
                ||infix.charAt(i) == '%' ||infix.charAt(i) ==' ' ||infix.charAt(i) == '0' 
                ||infix.charAt(i) == '1' || infix.charAt(i) =='2' || infix.charAt(i) =='3' 
                ||infix.charAt(i) == '4' ||infix.charAt(i) == '5' ||infix.charAt(i) == '6' 
                ||infix.charAt(i) == '7' || infix.charAt(i) =='8' ||infix.charAt(i) == '9'){

        }else{
            throw new InvalidCharacterException(infix.charAt(i));
        }

    }
```

Infix is the variable name of my user input as a StringBuffer.

Comment: Check the conditional statement in the push method in my answer. It can replace the uber long conditional statement in yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Scanner to validate your string:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);        
    String validationResult = scanner.findInLine("[^0-9()+\\-*\\/%]+");
    if (validationResult != null) {
        // Invalid character found.
        throw new InvalidCharacterException("Invalid character: " + validationResult);
    }
```

The findInLine method returns a String with the characters that match the regex and the regex looks for any character not valid in your validation. The findInLine only returns a non null String when there are any invalid characters in the String.

Comment: What do I need to denote so that an empty whitespace is also a valid character?

Comment: Just add the space or any other valid characer in the regex. 
For adding the space you can use: "[^0-9()+\\-*\\/% ]+"  (Notice the space added between the '%' and ']')

Comment: This is what I was hoping to do from the start, my for loop method was a pitiful attempt at a workaround. I had looked at the code for this but couldn't understand how to implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (for an [example](http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html)) and then loop over each character (in each token) and throw your Exception if your criteria are met (e.g. look at [Character.isDigit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29)) or just write your own method to test against acceptable characters (e.g. is char is contained in"()0123456789+-*/%").

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, but I don't know how to do it which is why I came here. I'm trying to write something that will either look at another string that contains those values, or trying to write a regex to do it for me, but I don't know how I would create the regex for what I have desired. I've never used a scanner to parse a string like that either, I've been trying to read tutorials about it but I keep coming up with much less info than desired.

Answer (score 1):

In your code this is probably better because it does the same thing.
Btw it probably should be i < infix.length() not <=

```
 for(int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++){
        char x = infix.charAt(i);
        if(!(Character.isDigit(x) || x == '/' || x == '*' ||
           x == '+'|| x== '-' || x=='%' || x == '\n'))
            throw new InvalidCharacterException(x);


        /* what you want to do if valid*/

 }
```

Comment: If it's valid, it just goes on to implement the rest of the code I have written to convert it from infix to postfix. I am using a stack to do this, but as part of what I'm doing my method that I am converting is supposed to throw the exception

Comment: @Neonjoe woops removed the irrelevant stack, check my answer now. Hopefully thats the conditional statement your looking for. And I think there's a bit of a logical error in your loop.

Comment: I tried using something like what you had written, but instead of isLetterOrDigit i'm just using !Character.isDigit(x) but every time I try to actually run the code just using a simple 1 + 2 it is throwing an InvalidCharacterException for 1

Comment: @Neonjoe maybe its because of boolean logic? You should use parenthesis when you apply ! so that there are no sudden  || becoming &&. Nevertheless try it :)

Comment: @Neonjoe BTW you should also check if its a '\n' character.

Comment: I've tried multiple different methods of implementing it within a for loop and every time I'm either getting an invalid input for 1 or for my empty whitespace. Is x == ' ' not a valid argument for whitespace? Is there a break character I need or something?